Prove that two chords of a circle bisect each other if and only if both of them are diameteres
I encountered this question in Challenge and thrills of pre college mathematics.
I have come up with this proof, please tell me is this right (i am relatively new to proof writing) also how can i write this more mathematically?
Proof:
Let there be a circle S with center O, let two distinct and non-overlapping chords AB and CD that do not pass through O bisect each other  at E, this implies that measure of angle AEO = 90 degrees = angle DEO and this means both the chords are overlapping thus two such chords must pass through the center.

More strongly, a chord that bisects any other chord must be a diameter.

I think you've changed names partway through. Is $O$ the circle with center $S$, or is the center $O$? If it's the former, then I don't know what "the line $OE$" could mean. I also don't see, from the construction, why there's any angle of 90 degrees -- perhaps you could be explicit and say "the angle AEO is 90 degrees" or something like that, and then cite a theorem that explains why the angle is 90 degrees.

See this: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII4.html

@YvesDaoust What I meant is that if a chord bisects some other chord, then it must be a diameter.

The part "if" is evident. It remains the "only if". So let us the chord $\overline{AB}=2a$ non diameter and another chord $\overline{CD}$ of lenght $l$. Supossing $\overline{CD}$ bisects $\overline{AB}$ at the midpoint, say $O$, of it, so we have $\overline{CO}=x$ and   $\overline{OD}=y$.
Then $x+y=l$ and $xy=a^2$ from which $x^2-lx+a^2=0$ and $2x=l^2\pm\sqrt{l^2-4a^2}$. The only possibility that $x=y$ is that $l^2-4a^2=0$ which yields $l=2a$ and because the chords intersect we see that $\overline{CD}$ is exactly $\overline{AB}$, contradiction.
